# Injecting fields into Java JPA fields

Tags: java, playframework

I'm no pro with Java, so I need a little help. I'm using the Play Framework.

I have an Entity class which extends GenericModel with fields like the following:

```
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
```

I want to add an additional field using a getter, let's call it getToString, which basically contains a read only string with the string representation of the entity.

I need this because the object is getting sent as a JSON response, and my JavaScript will read this field, and display it where for example the entity needs to be represented as a string.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Does anyone else have an idea about this?

Comment: Our problem is with GsonBuilder! The version we have doesn't support getters and setters.

Comment: Could you explain a little more - do you need the new property as a field, or as a getter, or both? Why?

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I'm having was a side effect of using GsonBuilder. The builder doesn't appear to be parsing getters and setters, unless the source of the library is modified, which I'm not willing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on the Play framework, but probably you should have a look at the @Transient annotation.

Fields (and getters/setters if you are using JPA property access) marked with @Transient will be ignored by JPA, but usually be considered by other frameworks.

Comment: I've added a member variable with @Transient, and it shows up in my JSON response! Nice. It won't show up as a member function though. Trying to implement as getToString()

Comment: Play is completely ignoring my getter method. The member variable works fine, but off course, I need a method...

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong) you want a read-only method that will return a string representation (JSon format) of the entity.

You could just override the default toString method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "your_json_string";
}
```

and call it when needed

Comment: Nope, I need to add it as an extra read only field, called toString, or anything for that matter.

The entity gets serialized using GsonBuilder, and I need the toString to be just another column, that contains the string as an additional field.

If I override toString method, it won't show up in my JSON response.